# Как полностью руссифицировать интерфейс мобильного приложения?

Tags: android, actionbar, локализация

Я пишу словесную игру типа *Эрудита* и хотел бы, чтобы интерфейс приложения (для `minSdkVersion="8"`) был полностью (и только!) на русском языке.

То есть мобильное приложение должно *всегда* быть на русском языке - без возможности переключения и независимо от телефонных настроек.

Поэтому я добавил следующий программный код в **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

И наряду с файлом **res/values/strings.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Words by Farber</string>
    <string name="action_swap">Swap</string>
    <string name="action_shuffle">Shuffle</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

я создал еще файл **res/values-ru/strings.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Слова Фарбера</string>
    <string name="action_swap">Поменять</string>
    <string name="action_shuffle">Помешать</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Настройки</string>
</resources>
```

К сожалению, строка `app_name` показывается в **ActionBar** все еще на английском языке (в то время как меню и остальные кнопки руссифицированы):

[image: Android app]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно всегда везде, и только на русском , зачем вы делаете вобще английский вариант? Много свободного времени для ненужной работы?
Не надо ничего выдумывать, выставлять принудительные локали  - просто пишите а `res/values/` на русском и все.

Это место для дефолтных значений, которые будут использоваться в случае, когда ничего более подходящего не будет найдено. При этом нет никакого правила, что дефолтные значения должны быть непременно в английской локализации.
Я понимаю, что сейчас принято прогибаться под запад, считать его по умолчанию дефолтным, но для их языка есть отдельное достойное место - `values-en`

В вашем случае, какая бы локаль не была на устройстве, при отсуствии языковых квалификаторов (values-ru, values-en) ресурсы будут браться из дефолтной (values) в которой будет русская локализация.

Comment: Логичный ответ, спасибо. Просто из моего опыта с другими ОС: если писать русские слова в дефолтные ресурсы, то в какой-то момент программу или скрипт *переклинит* - и она начнет показывать кракозябры.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Используйте кодировку utf8 и ничего не переклинит